# Security Essentials Update Script

Tags: windows-7, script, batch, ms-security-essentials

Is there a way to write a batch file to automatically update Microsoft security essentials for Windows 7?

If so, could you please help me write it?

Comment: Just enable automatic Windows Updates and MSE signature updates will be installed automatically.

Comment: I know, but it seems that i find myself doing updates more often than the windows updater does, so i wanted a quick way to do it manually instead of having to wait for windows updater to search and then find the update and do all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need 1 command:

```
"%programfiles%\Microsoft Security Client\Antimalware\MpCmdRun.exe" SignatureUpdate
```

Create a shortcut to your desktop or you can also create a scheduled task to update the signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Security Essentials includes a **command-line utility** which can be used to update the virus/malware definitions. The utility is named **MpCmdRun.exe**.
You can use the following script for updating:

> "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Security Essentials\MpCmdRun.exe" -SignatureUpdate

And schedule that batch file to run automatically using **Task Scheduler**.

If you don't turn off Automatic Windows Update, the Microsoft Security Essential will get automatically updated.

**See detailed instructions here:**
[Detailed Command Line Options](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/updating-microsoft-security-essentials-using-command-line/)
[Third Party Utility for Automatic Updating](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/mse-update-utility-addictivetips-apps/) (Not Recommended)

Comment: Thank you, but the directory was wrong, i found "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Security Client\MpCmdRun.exe" -SignatureUpdate to work, under my computer the there is no folder Microsoft Security Essentials, it's Security Client.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion, I think it was previously in that location.

Comment: Possible, but thank you anyways. It's all fine :)